# How to stop WordPress from filtering the full-width space in the editor?

Tags: wordpress, editor

I want to input the full-width space in WordPress editor. But WordPress just filtered and deleted it. How to stop WordPress from filtering the full-width space in the editor?

Beacuse I want to achive the following layout(in Chinese):

> 电话：1234567890
>
> 0987654321

In the second line, I want to align at the line above with the tel number. So I have to input 3 "Chinese space"(full-width space). But WordPress just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
&nbsp;
```

Or in your case:

```
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 0987654321
```

Comment: That also get filtered.